# How do I disable / enable sections of my website with PHP + Checkboxes?

Tags: php, checkbox

I need help with enableing/disableing parts of my website.

```
    <p>Disabled Sections:</p>
    <form id="e-d-check" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="SRS" onchange="document.getElementById('e-d-check').submit()">SkiRegionSimulator 2012</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Bilder" onchange="document.getElementById('e-d-check').submit()">Bilder</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="KWS" onchange="document.getElementById('e-d-check').submit()">Klimawandel-Stunde</input>
    </form>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Größe</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Download</th>
            </tr>

            <?php 
                if (isset($_POST['SRS'])) {
                    echo 'Disabled SkiRegionSimulator 2012';
                } else {
                    include'SRS.php';
                }
            ?>
```

Everytime I uncheck the box it checks itself again...

Comment: onchange typo. Also, I don't see where you mark them disabled?

Comment: `oncahnge` should be `onchange`

Comment: It checks itself because you set it in the html code as checked. Always.

Comment: K thanks. But still it doesn't work. When I disable the section, it unchecks itself so I can't remove the check because there is no check so I can't enable the section anymore.

Comment: Trying to use variables doesn't work for me. IDK if I'm using it correctly but could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different but similar approach with submit onclick.

```
<?php 
$check_SRS = "";
$check_Bilder = "";
$check_KWS = "";
if (isset($_POST['SRS']) && intval($_POST['SRS']) == 1) { $check_SRS = "checked";}
if (isset($_POST['Bilder']) && intval($_POST['Bilder']) == 1) { $check_Bilder = "checked";}
if (isset($_POST['KWS']) && intval($_POST['KWS']) == 1) { $check_KWS = "checked";}
?>
<p>Disabled Sections:</p>
   <form id="e-d-check" method="post">
     <input type="checkbox" name="SRS" value="1" onclick="submit()" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($check_SRS); ?>>SkiRegionSimulator 2012</input>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Bilder" value="1" onclick="submit()" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($check_Bilder); ?>>Bilder</input>
     <input type="checkbox" name="KWS" value="1" onclick="submit()" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($check_KWS); ?>>Klimawandel-Stunde</input>
   </form>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Größe</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <th>Download</th>
  </tr>
  <?php 
  if (isset($_POST['SRS']) && intval($_POST['SRS']) == 1) {
    echo 'Disabled SkiRegionSimulator 2012';
  } else {
    include'SRS.php';
  }
  ?>
```

A version of elseif statements to accommodate what are assumed to be the other includes depending on the state of the checkboxes - if one only can be checked:

```
<?php
if(intval($_POST['SRS']) == 1){
   echo 'Disabled SkiRegionSimulator 2012';
}elseif(intval($_POST['SRS']) != 1){
   include'SRS.php';
}elseif(intval($_POST['Bilder']) == 1){
   echo 'Disabled Bilder';
}elseif(intval($_POST['Bilder']) != 1){
   include'Bilder.php';
}elseif(intval($_POST['KWS']) == 1){
   echo 'Disabled KWS';
}elseif(intval($_POST['KWS']) != 1){
   include'KWS.php';
}
?>
```

if more than one can be checked:

```
 <?php
 if(intval($_POST['SRS']) == 1){
 echo 'Disabled SkiRegionSimulator 2012';
 }else{
 include'SRS.php';
 }

 if(intval($_POST['Bilder']) == 1){
 echo 'Disabled Bilder';
 }else{
 include'Bilder.php';
 }

 if(intval($_POST['KWS']) == 1){
 echo 'Disabled KWS';
 }else{
 include'KWS.php';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Magic! Really glad to hear that - you should look at safe ways to include - you might not want just anyone to find your include and open it separately - though that may not matter to you. I thought this summed it up very well http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=144  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works for you:

```
<?php
    $disabled = array();
    $disabled['SRS'] = isset($_POST['SRS']) && (int)$_POST['SRS'] === 1;
    $disabled['Bilder'] = isset($_POST['Bilder']) && (int)$_POST['Bilder'] === 1;
    $disabled['KWS'] = isset($_POST['KWS']) && (int)$_POST['KWS'] === 1;
?>
<p>Disabled Sections:</p>
<form id="e-d-check" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($disabled['SRS'] === true) echo "checked"; ?> name="SRS" onchange="document.getElementById('e-d-check').submit()">SkiRegionSimulator 2012</input>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($disabled['Bilder'] === true) echo "checked"; ?> name="Bilder" onchange="document.getElementById('e-d-check').submit()">Bilder</input>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($disabled['KWS'] === true) echo "checked"; ?> name="KWS" onchange="document.getElementById('e-d-check').submit()">Klimawandel-Stunde</input>
</form>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Größe</th>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Download</th>
        </tr>

        <?php 
            if ($disabled['SRS'] === true) {
                echo 'Disabled SkiRegionSimulator 2012';
            } else {
                include'SRS.php';
            }
        ?>
```

We control what checkbox is checked by using the (guess!) `checked` attribute. If you are using XHTML then change `checked` to `checked="checked"`

Comment: This one displays me a white page. But still thanks I found a solution :)

Comment: @Steve You are right, I mixed the casting with the function :). Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: I must admit I am not clear what the difference is between the two methods as `(int)` seems to be the only time I have found that structure in the PHP that I use. I liked your method though and upvoted it - though I couldn't get onchange to submit and had to use `onclick()`.